# Issue with latest curl 7.55.1 with android-ndk-r10b

Tags: curl, android-ndk, libcurl

I am getting an error while compiling curl 7.55.1 with android-ndk-r10b.
Please help me, I am not able to figure out this.

Before that I was using 7.38, now updating latest curl 7.55.1 with openssl 1.1.0f.
Below are the logs.

```
CC(target) out/Debug/obj.target/cURL/third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/easy.o
In file included from ../../../../../tools/platform/android/host-osx/android-ndk-r10b/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include/sys/_types.h:40:0,
                 from ../../../../../tools/platform/android/host-osx/android-ndk-r10b/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include/stdint.h:32,
                 from ../../../../../tools/platform/android/host-osx/android-ndk-r10b/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include/sys/types.h:34,
                 from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/include/curl/system.h:479,
                 from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/include/curl/curl.h:38,
                 from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/curl_setup.h:142,
                 from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/easy.c:23:
../../../../../tools/platform/android/host-osx/android-ndk-r10b/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include/machine/_types.h:46:14: warning: ISO C90 does not support 'long long' [-Wlong-long]
 typedef long long  __int64_t;
              ^
../../../../../tools/platform/android/host-osx/android-ndk-r10b/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include/machine/_types.h:48:23: warning: ISO C90 does not support 'long long' [-Wlong-long]
 typedef unsigned long long __uint64_t;
                       ^
In file included from ../../../../../tools/platform/android/host-osx/android-ndk-r10b/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include/linux/posix_types.h:41:0,
                 from ../../../../../tools/platform/android/host-osx/android-ndk-r10b/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include/sys/types.h:37,
                 from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/include/curl/system.h:479,
                 from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/include/curl/curl.h:38,
                 from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/curl_setup.h:142,
                 from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/easy.c:23:
../../../../../tools/platform/android/host-osx/android-ndk-r10b/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include/asm/posix_types.h:43:14: warning: ISO C90 does not support 'long long' [-Wlong-long]
 typedef long long __kernel_loff_t;
              ^
In file included from ../../../../../tools/platform/android/host-osx/android-ndk-r10b/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include/sys/types.h:38:0,
                 from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/include/curl/system.h:479,
                 from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/include/curl/curl.h:38,
                 from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/curl_setup.h:142,
                 from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/easy.c:23:
../../../../../tools/platform/android/host-osx/android-ndk-r10b/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include/asm/types.h:29:25: warning: ISO C90 does not support 'long long' [-Wlong-long]
 typedef __signed__ long long __s64;
                         ^
../../../../../tools/platform/android/host-osx/android-ndk-r10b/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include/asm/types.h:30:23: warning: ISO C90 does not support 'long long' [-Wlong-long]
 typedef unsigned long long __u64;
                       ^
In file included from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/include/curl/curl.h:38:0,
                 from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/curl_setup.h:142,
                 from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/easy.c:23:
../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/include/curl/system.h:433:45: warning: ISO C90 does not support 'long long' [-Wlong-long]
 #    define CURL_TYPEOF_CURL_OFF_T     long long
                                             ^
../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/include/curl/system.h:496:11: note: in expansion of macro 'CURL_TYPEOF_CURL_OFF_T'
   typedef CURL_TYPEOF_CURL_OFF_T curl_off_t;
           ^
In file included from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/curl_setup_once.h:31:0,
                 from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/curl_setup.h:679,
                 from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/easy.c:23:
../../../../../tools/platform/android/host-osx/android-ndk-r10b/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include/stdlib.h:65:13: warning: ISO C90 does not support 'long long' [-Wlong-long]
 extern long long strtoll(const char *, char **, int);
             ^
../../../../../tools/platform/android/host-osx/android-ndk-r10b/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include/stdlib.h:67:22: warning: ISO C90 does not support 'long long' [-Wlong-long]
 extern unsigned long long strtoull(const char *, char **, int);
                      ^
../../../../../tools/platform/android/host-osx/android-ndk-r10b/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include/stdlib.h:78:13: warning: ISO C90 does not support 'long long' [-Wlong-long]
 extern long long atoll(const char *);
             ^
../../../../../tools/platform/android/host-osx/android-ndk-r10b/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include/stdlib.h:94:24: warning: ISO C90 does not support 'long long' [-Wlong-long]
 static __inline__ long long llabs(long long __n) {
                        ^
../../../../../tools/platform/android/host-osx/android-ndk-r10b/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include/stdlib.h:94:40: warning: ISO C90 does not support 'long long' [-Wlong-long]
 static __inline__ long long llabs(long long __n) {
                                        ^
../../../../../tools/platform/android/host-osx/android-ndk-r10b/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include/stdlib.h: In function 'llabs':
../../../../../tools/platform/android/host-osx/android-ndk-r10b/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include/stdlib.h:95:19: warning: use of C99 long long integer constant [-Wlong-long]
     return (__n < 0LL) ? -__n : __n;
                   ^
../../../../../tools/platform/android/host-osx/android-ndk-r10b/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include/stdlib.h: At top level:
../../../../../tools/platform/android/host-osx/android-ndk-r10b/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include/stdlib.h:163:10: warning: ISO C90 does not support 'long long' [-Wlong-long]
     long long int  quot;
          ^
../../../../../tools/platform/android/host-osx/android-ndk-r10b/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include/stdlib.h:164:10: warning: ISO C90 does not support 'long long' [-Wlong-long]
     long long int  rem;
          ^
../../../../../tools/platform/android/host-osx/android-ndk-r10b/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include/stdlib.h:167:29: warning: ISO C90 does not support 'long long' [-Wlong-long]
 extern lldiv_t   lldiv(long long, long long);
                             ^
../../../../../tools/platform/android/host-osx/android-ndk-r10b/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include/stdlib.h:167:40: warning: ISO C90 does not support 'long long' [-Wlong-long]
 extern lldiv_t   lldiv(long long, long long);
                                        ^
In file included from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/curl_setup_once.h:53:0,
                 from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/curl_setup.h:679,
                 from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/easy.c:23:
../../../../../tools/platform/android/host-osx/android-ndk-r10b/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include/sys/stat.h:78:19: warning: ISO C90 does not support 'long long' [-Wlong-long]
     unsigned long long  st_dev;
                   ^
../../../../../tools/platform/android/host-osx/android-ndk-r10b/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include/sys/stat.h:88:19: warning: ISO C90 does not support 'long long' [-Wlong-long]
     unsigned long long  st_rdev;
                   ^
../../../../../tools/platform/android/host-osx/android-ndk-r10b/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include/sys/stat.h:91:10: warning: ISO C90 does not support 'long long' [-Wlong-long]
     long long           st_size;
          ^
../../../../../tools/platform/android/host-osx/android-ndk-r10b/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include/sys/stat.h:93:19: warning: ISO C90 does not support 'long long' [-Wlong-long]
     unsigned long long  st_blocks;
                   ^
../../../../../tools/platform/android/host-osx/android-ndk-r10b/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include/sys/stat.h:104:19: warning: ISO C90 does not support 'long long' [-Wlong-long]
     unsigned long long  st_ino;
                   ^
../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/easy.c:343:19: error: conflicting types for 'curl_easy_init'
 struct Curl_easy *curl_easy_init(void)
                   ^
In file included from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/include/curl/curl.h:2546:0,
                 from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/curl_setup.h:142,
                 from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/easy.c:23:
../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/include/curl/easy.h:28:19: note: previous declaration of 'curl_easy_init' was here
 CURL_EXTERN CURL *curl_easy_init(void);
                   ^
../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/easy.c:374:10: error: conflicting types for 'curl_easy_setopt'
 CURLcode curl_easy_setopt(struct Curl_easy *data, CURLoption tag, ...)
          ^
In file included from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/include/curl/curl.h:2546:0,
                 from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/curl_setup.h:142,
                 from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/easy.c:23:
../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/include/curl/easy.h:29:22: note: previous declaration of 'curl_easy_setopt' was here
 CURL_EXTERN CURLcode curl_easy_setopt(CURL *curl, CURLoption option, ...);
                      ^
../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/easy.c:811:10: error: conflicting types for 'curl_easy_perform'
 CURLcode curl_easy_perform(struct Curl_easy *data)
          ^
In file included from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/include/curl/curl.h:2546:0,
                 from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/curl_setup.h:142,
                 from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/easy.c:23:
../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/include/curl/easy.h:30:22: note: previous declaration of 'curl_easy_perform' was here
 CURL_EXTERN CURLcode curl_easy_perform(CURL *curl);
                      ^
../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/easy.c:832:6: error: conflicting types for 'curl_easy_cleanup'
 void curl_easy_cleanup(struct Curl_easy *data)
      ^
In file included from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/include/curl/curl.h:2546:0,
                 from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/curl_setup.h:142,
                 from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/easy.c:23:
../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/include/curl/easy.h:31:18: note: previous declaration of 'curl_easy_cleanup' was here
 CURL_EXTERN void curl_easy_cleanup(CURL *curl);
                  ^
../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/easy.c:849:10: error: conflicting types for 'curl_easy_getinfo'
 CURLcode curl_easy_getinfo(struct Curl_easy *data, CURLINFO info, ...)
          ^
In file included from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/include/curl/curl.h:2546:0,
                 from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/curl_setup.h:142,
                 from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/easy.c:23:
../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/include/curl/easy.h:46:22: note: previous declaration of 'curl_easy_getinfo' was here
 CURL_EXTERN CURLcode curl_easy_getinfo(CURL *curl, CURLINFO info, ...);
                      ^
../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/easy.c:869:19: error: conflicting types for 'curl_easy_duphandle'
 struct Curl_easy *curl_easy_duphandle(struct Curl_easy *data)
                   ^
In file included from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/include/curl/curl.h:2546:0,
                 from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/curl_setup.h:142,
                 from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/easy.c:23:
../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/include/curl/easy.h:61:19: note: previous declaration of 'curl_easy_duphandle' was here
 CURL_EXTERN CURL *curl_easy_duphandle(CURL *curl);
                   ^
../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/easy.c:970:6: error: conflicting types for 'curl_easy_reset'
 void curl_easy_reset(struct Curl_easy *data)
      ^
In file included from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/include/curl/curl.h:2546:0,
                 from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/curl_setup.h:142,
                 from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/easy.c:23:
../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/include/curl/easy.h:74:18: note: previous declaration of 'curl_easy_reset' was here
 CURL_EXTERN void curl_easy_reset(CURL *curl);
                  ^
../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/easy.c:1007:10: error: conflicting types for 'curl_easy_pause'
 CURLcode curl_easy_pause(struct Curl_easy *data, int action)
          ^
In file included from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/curl_setup.h:142:0,
                 from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/easy.c:23:
../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/include/curl/curl.h:2529:22: note: previous declaration of 'curl_easy_pause' was here
 CURL_EXTERN CURLcode curl_easy_pause(CURL *handle, int bitmask);
                      ^
../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/easy.c:1089:10: error: conflicting types for 'curl_easy_recv'
 CURLcode curl_easy_recv(struct Curl_easy *data, void *buffer, size_t buflen,
          ^
In file included from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/include/curl/curl.h:2546:0,
                 from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/curl_setup.h:142,
                 from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/easy.c:23:
../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/include/curl/easy.h:84:22: note: previous declaration of 'curl_easy_recv' was here
 CURL_EXTERN CURLcode curl_easy_recv(CURL *curl, void *buffer, size_t buflen,
                      ^
../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/easy.c:1116:10: error: conflicting types for 'curl_easy_send'
 CURLcode curl_easy_send(struct Curl_easy *data, const void *buffer,
          ^
In file included from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/include/curl/curl.h:2546:0,
                 from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/curl_setup.h:142,
                 from ../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/easy.c:23:
../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/include/curl/easy.h:95:22: note: previous declaration of 'curl_easy_send' was here
 CURL_EXTERN CURLcode curl_easy_send(CURL *curl, const void *buffer,
                      ^
make: *** [out/Debug/obj.target/cURL/third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/easy.o] Error 1
```

Comment: @Daniel  Thank you so much for the reply.
I added "BUILDING_LIBCURL" into my curl.mk file and that error was gone.
But I am getting a new error now. please help me, I am struggling from last 2 days.
Below are the logs.

'<command-line>:0:6: error: expected identifier or '(' before numeric constant
../../../../third_party/unix/curl/curl-7.55.1/lib/ftplistparser.c:159:7: note: in expansion of macro 'UNIX'
     } UNIX; '

Comment: Why are you using a standalone *.mk file? Personally I am using several Gradle Exec to automate creation of a standalone compiler and autoconf-based build. Then link created static library with primary JNI bindings file (which is compiled by CMake with Android Studio integration). Works like a charm.

Comment: Above issue is resolved and now curl is successful compiled but now I am not able to make https call or secure call even if SSL support is enabled with openssl-1.1.0f.

Comment: If you have followed my recommendation, you are also supposed to 1) build and install openssl (using `make && make install`) to some directory within your build dir 2) pass `--with-ssl=<path to openssl installation dir>` to configure script 3) Link your final library with openssl libraries (bunch of *.a files installation dir). Make sure, that you are building, installing and linking openssl static libraries.

Comment: @user1643723 thanks for reply, I did same steps as you mentioned above. my config: ./configure --host=arm-linux-androideabi --with-ssl=/usr/local/openssl/                                                                                    it also showing SSL support: Enabled but still it gives error:0x99dc2460 CURL error occurred: Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl